# PostgreSQL doesn't like columns of type double

Tags: postgresql, heroku, playframework-2.0

I have a Play 2.0 application that I'm attempting to deploy to Heroku. After it successfully compiles and runs on localhost, Heroku complains that **type "double" does not exist**. The application itself is extremely similar to the JavaTodoList tutorial located here:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaTodoList

Except the model has Double fields, not String fields, like so:

```
package models;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import play.data.validation.Constraints.Required;
import play.db.ebean.Model;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class GeoPoint extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Required
    public Double latitude;

    @Required
    public Double longitude;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static Finder<Long, GeoPoint> find = new Finder(Long.class, GeoPoint.class);

    public static List<GeoPoint> all() {
        return find.all();
    }

    public static void create(GeoPoint task) {
        task.save();
    }

    public static void delete(Long id) {
        find.ref(id).delete();
    }

}
```

I believe it has something to do with the PostgreSQL driver generating SQL with columns of type **double** instead of **double precision**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your ORM is but we are running ebean on heroku.

And this is how we handle numbers with precision

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "e_company_billing_contract_item")
   public class CompanyBillingContractItem extends GenericDBO{
   @JsonIgnore
   @ManyToOne
   private CompanyBillingContract contract;
   private String name;
   private int nbrIncluded;
   private int maxLimit;
   @Column(columnDefinition = "NUMERIC")
   private BigDecimal price;
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but the Column is exactly what I needed. Thanks!